# Use a substituted for sup tag in PDFBundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I want a higher number in the PHPPdf PDFBundle in Symfony2. But the bundle don't accept the `sup` tag.

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        <div>
        Some written text<sup>1</sup>
        </div>
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```

So I need to substitute it with CSS and I try something like `<span vertical-align="super" font-size="5pt"></span>` but it don't work. Anyone a solution for this? And thank you for your help.

Comment: Wrong title: PDFBundle, not PHPBundle

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. But I'm not sure if it always works. 
My solution use the attribute line-height.

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        <div>
        Some written text<span font-style="italic" font-size="5" line-height="8">1</span>
        </div>
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```